# How to concatenate a 2D array into every 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the same 2D array, `A` with shape `(n, m)`,  into every 2D array of a 3D array, `B` with shape `(N, n, k)`.

I tried with stacks and concatenate but it didn't work due to only one dimension match. I tried the following example to test the idea:

```py
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.ones((2,3,4))

np.hstack((a,b))
```

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

What I was expecting is the following result:

```py
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [3., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [3., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

I am aware that it is possible to do it with a for loop but I am looking for a more compact and optimised solution.

Comment: np.concatenate should be the right way. you could also look at np.hstack, or np.vstack. could you provide an example of what you tried?

Comment: You have to pre-expand `a` to the size you want. I think you can use an explicit call to `broadcast_to` or so

Comment: Also, your example does not fit the description very well. Please fix that.

Comment: You need to extend `A` to (N,n,m) first, possibly with a (1,n,m) intermediate step. tile or repeat might help.  Or `stack` a list of N `A`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit messy but its getting the job done

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.ones((2,3,4))
a=np.expand_dims(a,axis=0)
a=np.concatenate((a,a),axis=0)
np.dstack((a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a `(3, 1)` array that you want to prepend to a `(2, 3, 4)` array as did if it were broadcast to `(2, 3, 1)`. This is one of those cases where you would have to do the [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) yourself. If you use [`broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to), you will get an object that does not copy the original data, and is suitable for copying into a new array, as a minimum:

```
c = np.broadcast_to(a, b.shape[0:1] + a.shape)
result = np.concatenate((c, b), axis=2)
```

https://ideone.com/ypDpyT